# Can you pass a database Id into a Javascript function and get back a parameter corresponding to that Id in Asp,NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2022, .Net 6, ASP.Net Core and SQL Server.
I am very new to all of this and I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.

I have two buttons that invoke a javascript function and pass a number:

```
<div id=sidebar>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="DisplayData('1')" value="World1"><br>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="DisplayData('2')" value="World2">
</div>
```

I want the function to treat this number as an Id of an item from a connected database. Then I want to display the Name property of that database item in a div.

```
<script>
        function DisplayData(id){    
            document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = //What do I put here;
        }
</script>

<div id=main>
     <p id="name"></p>
</div>
```

Is there something I can do in javascript or am I on a completely wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the step to read the entity from your DB. Your front-end JS code should send an AJAX call to your .net core backend to fetch that entity from the DB with seletec ID. And then you can display whatever property from the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to pass `id` to action,and action return related name.Then change `innerHtml` with the related name in js.Here is a demo:

js:

```
function DisplayData(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetName",
                data: { id:id},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (name) {
                    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
                }
            })
            
        }
```

action:

```
public JsonResult GetName(int id)
        {
            string name = //get name from database with the id
            return new JsonResult(name);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's exactly what I've been looking for. However I still can't display the data. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I try to get the name? I am using: `string name = _db.HomeWorlds.Single(a => a.HomeWorldId == id).Name;`, where HomeWorlds is the name of the Model, HomeWorldId is the primary key and Name is the property I want to get.